# BA (Baskerville) Math Font from micropress available?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

For several years now, I've been trying to get my hands on the BA Math Font from [micropress](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/bamath/bamain.htm).  But I can't find anyone who has it, or who is willing to sell it to me (including the original authors).  And the online ordering form at the referenced website doesn't do anything -- I've tried it.  As far as I can tell, this font has disappeared from the face of the planet! :)

Does anyone know where I can buy this font?  Anyone have any information that might help me to track this down?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on another SE site. I think it would get better answers on the site dedicated to this (graphical design? typography?) which is now out of beta, as I understand it.

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic --- the fonts were specifically sold as supporting TeX (in case anyone has forgotten, MicroPress was the company which made VisualTeX).